# How can I make sure I'm implementing the Open/Closed principle?

Tags: c#, solid-principles

Let's say I have a base class called `Shape` and I want to have each shape be able to return their own area.  I could either make `Shape` an interface or an abstract class (and possibly other ways) but the end result is that each shape will have a function called `Area`.

So let's say I have a collection like:

```
List<Shape> bag = loadShapesFromXML(...)
```

And if I want to add all of the areas together, I could do:

```
int total=0;
foreach (var s in bag)
   total += s.Area();
```

This follows the open/closed principle just fine.  The problem I have is `loadShapesFromXML`.  Assume my XML looks like this:

```
<bag>
  <circle id="1" radius="5" />
  <square id="2" length="3" />
  <rectangle id="3" length="6" width="7"/>
</bag>
```

My `loadShapesFromXML` method would have to examine each item in the "bag" to see what type of shape it is.  Other than using reflection to see if the type of shape is circle/square/rectangle, what else could I do to not have to modify this function every time I decide to add a new shape?

Comment: If you load them with the serializer, this problem should go away. Is that not an option?

Comment: May be better question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com if you are looking for generic guidance (based on title). Otherwise check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern

Comment: @BradletDotNET How would the problem go away? It would still need to calculate the shape based on each specific implementation of the derived `Shape` type, wouldnt it?

Comment: Is there a reason you've restricted yourself to not using reflection? What about using third party libraries which use reflection?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, he was concerned about using reflection to get the types. By using the serializer it will automatically serialize into the correct types (granted likely using reflection behind the scenes). He wouldn't have to modify the function for a new type though.

Answer (score 2):

Your shape objects are closed to modification by design - so you can't add `ReadFromXXXX` and `WriteToXXXX` methods. To implement serialization you can have some other component that understand mapping between data structure in storage and run-time objects - covered by [data mapper pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern).

Very basic "mapper" for Xml nodes would be dictionary of reader functions indexed by node name:

```
  var creatorsMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<XElement, Shape>>
     {{"rectangle", node => new Rectangle(node.Element(....) ...)}};
  ...
  shapes.Add(creatorsMap[node.Name](node));
```

If your concern is how to discover all possible shapes - than reflection is on possible approach to find all types, manually adding additional types in code or configuration is an option too. If you are using dependency injection container it may provide some way to build/help with such mapping method too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found a nice way of doing this.  I made some changes to my XML from above.

```
<bag>
  <circle id="1" radius="5">Circle 1</circle> />
  <square id="2" length="3">Square 1</square> />
  <rectangle id="3" length="6" width="7">Rectangle 1</rectangle>/>
</bag>
```

This is the abstract **shape** class.  Notice it has two constructors.  The second one is to pass in an XElement object found inside the "bag".

```
public abstract class shape
{
    private readonly string _ID;
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public shape(string id, string name)
    {
        _ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public shape(XElement element)
    {
        _ID = element.Attribute("id").Value;
        this.Name = element.Value;
    }

    public abstract XElement GetXElement();

    public abstract double Area();

}
```

Now here is an instance of a circle.  Note that the constructor takes the unique elements of that shape and populates the propert(ies) accordingly.  Also note the GetXElement will properly construct the XML node should you wish to write back to the XML file.

```
public class circle : shape
{
    public int Radius { get; set; }

    public circle(string id, string name, int radius)
        : base(id, name)
    {
        this.Radius = radius;
    }

    public circle(XElement element)
        : base(element)
    {
        this.Radius = int.Parse(element.Attribute("radius").Value);
    }

    public override XElement GetXElement()
    {
        return new XElement("circle", new XAttribute("id", this.id), new XAttribute("radius", this.Radius), this.Name);
    }

    public override double Area()
    {
        return Math.PI * Radius * Radius;
    }
}
```

And here is how you can use reflection to get the area using the Open/Closed Principle.  Note the shapes are all being constructed from the contents of the XML file, and the **Console.WriteLine(element)** statement generates the XML for you to use.  In this case the output will be the same as the input, but if you changed the properties of the shape in question this XML output will change to match.

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        double area=0;
        foreach (var shapeItem in doc.Descendants("bag").Descendants())
        {
            var type = Type.GetType("StackOverflowShapes." + shapeItem.Name + ",StackOverflowShapes");
            var myShape = (shape)Activator.CreateInstance(type, shapeItem);
            area += myShape.Area();
            var element = myShape.GetXElement();
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }

        Assert.Equal(129.5398, area, 4);
    }
```

So new shapes can now be added without modifying the routine to calculate the total area.  Additionally each shape is responsible for building their own XML representations, and can create an instance of itself from an XML representation.

Answer (score 0):

The logic will have to go somewhere but if reflection is out and you need  loadShapesFromXML to not change, you could define your Shape object class to be general rather than specific and have it include all dimension types.

```
class Shape
  var radius;
  var length;
  var width;
  var diagonal; //new ways of defining a shape would go here
  var id;
  var name;
```

Reflection is a better way to do it but at least this way you can make your bag of 
Shape objects without modifying your loadShapesFromXML method. You would however, have to modify your Shape class to deal with new shape types, and be able to infer which specific shape type it actually is (square, circle, etc).

```
if(id == 1)
  bag.add(new Circle(this));
else if(id == 2)
  bag.add(new Square(this));
...
```

Comment: Ughh... both approaches are really bad. Now he has to modify the base class any time he needs new data . That's no better than modifying the loader function (in fact its quite a bit worse). The second is alright as long as the Ids consistent, but isn't much better than what he started with.

Comment: A shape class cant have a radius property which is specific to a circle.

Comment: I asked my 5-year-old and he said that yes, a circle is indeed a shape. My generic shape idea would need to include radius as a valid way to create/measure a shape (which could be a circle).